# Python PyQt5 QTextBrowser hyperlink loses part of link

Tags: python, url, pyqt, pyqt5, qtextbrowser

Hi i have a small problem with hyperlink in QTextBrowser.

I create links with this code with ID from json parsing:

```
ID = data["response"]["recordings"][0]["id"]
aLink = " <a href=http://***/archive/edit?id=%s>%s</a>" % (ID, ID)

print(aLink)
```

When i print link i get:

```
<a href=http://***/archive/edit?id=17452>17452</a>
```

The problem is that when i use this to create hyperlink in QTextBrowser, the link is created but it holds only this:

```
http://***/archive/edit?id
```

Somehow i loose this part of code "=17452" when i append link to QtextBrowser

```
self.textBrowser.append(aLink)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the quotes:

```
<a href='some-url'> some-text</a>
        ^        ^
        |-quotes-|
```

Example:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ID = 17452
aLink = " <a href='http://***/archive/edit?id=%s'>%s</a>" % (ID, ID)
w = QTextBrowser()
w.append(aLink)
w.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```